# C - keeping printed terminal output in place

Tags: c, ncurses

I have a simple c program that is first printing information related to the users machine:

```
Header Info 1
Header Info 2
Header Info 3
```

I then print columns of data related to the above:

```
XX      XX      XX      XX      XX
XX      XX      XX      XX      XX
XX      XX      XX      XX      XX
XX      XX      XX      XX      XX
...
```

What I would like is to keep the top header information in place, then have the rest of the data print under it continuously.  This way the header info does not scroll off the top of the screen.  What is the easiest way to accomplish this?

**EDIT: I am on linux.**

Comment: Which platform, Linux, Windows, or MAC. If MAC, use the curses library. If Windows, open a console, and look at their documentation.

Comment: I edited the original post.  I am on linux.

Comment: You've got curses then. I've never actually written code for curses, but Informix 4GL uses it. There have to be C examples out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just based on your general description, you can do something like this.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <curses.h>

static int quit_flag;

void sigint_handler (int sig) {
    quit_flag = 1;
}

int main () {
    int i;
    WINDOW *w;
    signal(SIGINT, sigint_handler);
    w = initscr();
    scrollok(w, 1);
    wsetscrreg(w, 4, LINES-1);
    wprintw(w, "%s\n", "Info 1");
    wprintw(w, "%s\n", "Info 2");
    wprintw(w, "%s\n", "Info 3");
    wprintw(w, "%s\n", "Info 4");
    wrefresh(w);
    i = 0;
    wsetscrreg(w, 4, LINES-1);
    while (++i) {
        wprintw(w, "%d\n", i);
        wrefresh(w);
        if (quit_flag) break;
    }
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am getting that SIGINT is undeclared here.  Would you mind explaining its use or how it should be declared?

Comment: @user1764386: Need to include `<signal.h>`. Answer updated. It is used to clean up curses if you exit the program using Ctrl-C.

Comment: Two problems: (a) the call to `wsetscrreg` within the loop is unnecessary, and calling `endwin` in the signal handler is unsafe.  See the section on signal handlers in [`initscr`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_initscr.3x.html#h3-Signal-Handlers).

Comment: @ThomasDickey: Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The suggested answer has a couple of problems:

- the call to wsetscrreg within the loop is unnecessary
- calling endwin in the signal handler is unsafe. See the section on [signal handlers](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_initscr.3x.html#h3-Signal-Handlers) in the [`initscr`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_initscr.3x.html) manual page.

This is a corrected version:

```
#include <curses.h>

int main (void) {
    int i;
    WINDOW *w;
    w = initscr();
    scrollok(w, 1);
    wsetscrreg(w, 4, LINES-1);
    wprintw(w, "%s\n", "Info 1");
    wprintw(w, "%s\n", "Info 2");
    wprintw(w, "%s\n", "Info 3");
    wprintw(w, "%s\n", "Info 4");
    wrefresh(w);
    i = 0;
    while (++i) {
        wprintw(w, "%d\n", i);
        wrefresh(w);
    }
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

Further, realizing that the return value from `initscr` is `stdscr`, the program can be simplified:

```
#include <curses.h>

int main (void) {
    int i;
    initscr();
    scrollok(stdscr, 1);
    setscrreg(4, LINES-1);
    printw("%s\n", "Info 1");
    printw("%s\n", "Info 2");
    printw("%s\n", "Info 3");
    printw("%s\n", "Info 4");
    refresh();
    i = 0;
    while (++i) {
        printw("%d\n", i);
        refresh();
    }
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```